# Is there a way play Civilization 4 (DVD-ROM) on Windows 10? (without virtual machine / dual boot)

Tags: civilization-4, windows-10, drm

I recently got Civilization 4 but sadly am unable to play it on Windows 10 due to the SafeDisc DRM it employs.

Is there any way that I can play Civ4 on my system (preferably without virtual machine / dual boot)?

Comment: You have the retail version? I doubt the Steam version uses SafeDisk.

Comment: @user598527 Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From PC Gaming Wiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Civilization_4):

> **Retail**
>   The Complete Edition contains no DRM. Individual versions of the
>   game include DRM, but it can be removed through patches.

[links to the patches](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Civilization_IV#Essential_improvements)

Comment: Neither your answer not the wiki actually explain how to remove the DRM.

Comment: @OrangeDog: I don't understand, my quote ("can be removed through patches") tells how to remove DRM. I'm also sure that linking to "cracks" isn't allowed.

Comment: What patches? How do you apply them?

Comment: Install the 1.61 patch from https://www.2kgames.com/civ4/downloads.htm @OrangeDog

Answer (score -1):

I have the complete version of civ4 on one disc . This has no DMR and was cheap at a thrift store But still follow this process Put the disc in the cd player , right click open to see files , copy all files and paste to a folder not on c , close the folder and reopen right click on setup ex run as admin , this should start an install do custom location and choose this same folder outside drive c everything will install , you will get message to uninstall everything just close the window . Go back to your file click on civ4.exe or the warloads folder or other exe files and they will run . Do not make a shortcut of any kind to run anything or it may corrupt the process. Its not too hard to do as I'm 73 . This will work . I got this idea on line from someone who helped people run empire earth 2  on win 10